# SQL SERVER - Retrieve Last Entered Data

Tags: sql-server

I've searched for long time for getting last entered data in a table. But I got same answer.

```
SELECT TOP 1 CustomerName FROM Customers
ORDER BY CustomerID DESC;
```

My scenario is, how to get last data if that Customers table is having `CustomerName` column only? No other columns such as `ID` or `createdDate` I entered four names in following order.

James
Arun
Suresh
Bryen

Now I want to select last entered `CustomerName`, i.e., `Bryen`. How can I get it..?

Comment: There is no order in tables. There is no first or last row. If you want a specific order, you have to specify it with an `ORDER BY` clause. While you *could* use change tracking or CDC to get a list of all changes, this would be a serious abuse of change tracking and rather costly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find last row entered in a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19982804/find-last-row-entered-in-a-table)

Answer (score 0):

If the table is not properly designed (`IDENTITY`, `TIMESTAMP`, identifier generated using `SEQUENCE` etc.), `INSERT` order is not kept by SQL Server. So, "last" record is meaningless without some criteria to use for ordering.

One possible workaround is if, by chance, records in this table are linked to some other table records (FKs, 1:1 or 1:n connection) and that table has a timestamp or something similar and you can deduct insertion order.

More details about "ordering without criteria" can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345731/return-rows-in-the-exact-order-they-were-inserted) and [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2008/08/27/no-seatbelt-expecting-order-without-order-by.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

; with cte_new as (
select *,row_number() over(order by(select 1000)) as new from tablename
)
select * from cte_new where new=4